# SQL Server Alternative to Split String

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I cannot use the split_string function and I cannot alter the database to set the compatibility level to what I need.

I have a column with the following example values:

```
JohnDoe-123-fakestreet-02-2018-01-01-2018-12-03
SamSmith-ab1-concordia-16-2018-02-02-2018-11-03
JaneDoe-zxy-austin-11-2018-03-01-2018-03-16
HomerSimpson-999-Chicago-22-2018-04-01-2018-10-20
EricCartman-222-Madison-05-2018-05-01-2018-09-01
```

I need the 4th value in each row. I.e.:

```
02
16
11
22
05
```

How can I do this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Your results don't 'make sense.  The first three are from the fourth column.  The last two are from the second column.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. Everything is using the 4th value :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @TestData varchar(max) = 'JohnDoe-123-fakestreet-0299-2018-01-01-2018-12-03'

select @TestData
  , substring(
    @TestData
    , charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, 1)+1)+1)+1
    , (charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, 1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
    - (charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, charindex('-', @TestData, 1)+1)+1)+1) - 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your values follow the same pattern as in your example strings, the last part of the string is fixed width.  That means that you can just do:

```
select left(right(str, 24), 2)
```

Comment: However the result he is looking for is not always 2 chars...

Comment: @DaleBurrell . . . Interesting.  It is in all the strings the OP shows.  It isn't in the sample results.  I wonder which is more accurate.  I generally assume that zero-padded numbers are going to be fixed width.

Comment: Looks like the results switch to using the second column...